Is there now a citation for "D&D is not a physics simulation"?
The rules often lead to outcomes that differ from what one would expect from real-world physics, and answers here sometimes make the point that "D&D is not a physics simulation/simulator", that instead it is a game that has rules optimized for a fun and engaging gameplay experience. But is that claim supported by actual text we can refer to?
We had this same question for the original 5e ruleset. Back then, there was no outright citation in the 5e rules supporting this claim (although we had some fantastic answers, some based on 1e).
Is there a citation for it in the new 5e rules?

The peasant rail gun isn't physics either.

Hm is there any reason to add this new question instead of just adding the answer to the existing one at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196846/is-there-a-citation-for-dd-is-not-a-physics-simulation?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

@Cubic Yes, there is - I did ask a question on meta about it before posting. Agreed guidance is to post a new question. Details there.

@NobodytheHobgoblin thanks for clarifying

@KorvinStarmast: Right, but it's the physical implication of rules as written.  The fact that it doesn't remotely match real-world physics is the result of pushing rules-as-written outside the regime where they simulate a world that's realistic enough for narrative purposes.

@PeterCordes The "physical implication of rules as written." Only if you insist on interpreting the rules to reflect an actual planet in the real universe. When did people stop playing Dungeons & Dragons for its sword-and-sorcery fun and start insisting any or all its rules be consistent with Real World Physics? This modern fad of "as realistic as possible" sucks the life out of games that had (and have, right?) as their sole purpose escaping from the real world through imagination and social interraction.

@JBH: As the authors of the 2024 DMG point out, it's up to the DM to make the world make sense by not blindly following RAW when pushed outside the regime where its simplifications still match what human players imagine should / shouldn't be possible.  With sane humans having an override, we can have simple fun rules without having them be exploitable in stupid ways.

@PeterCordes And its helpful that the DMG makes this point so clearly, so one can show that that is the way it is supposed to work.

Yes, there is such a citation now
We now have a fully official statement on it for 2024 5e (from the free rules, and the corresponding section of the 2024 DMG). It even makes reference to the infamous Peasant Railgun as an example:

Rules Aren’t Physics. The rules of the game are meant to provide a fun game experience, not to describe the laws of physics in the worlds of D&D, let alone the real world. Don’t let players argue that a bucket brigade of ordinary people can accelerate a spear to light speed by all using the Ready action to pass the spear to the next person in line. The Ready action facilitates heroic action; it doesn’t define the physical limitations of what can happen in a 6-second combat round.


While this is in the Free Rules, should we list the canonical source as the 2024 DMG?

@GuybrushMcKenzie Unpublished sources cannot be canonical sources.

@GuybrushMcKenzie be Patient, add a page later.

@ThomasMarkov, it's published here: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/dmg-2024/the-basics#PlayersExploitingtheRules

@nonymous It is not published yet: it will be out in around 6 days...

@nonymous That’s the early access digital version, which technically could be revoked before print copies hit shelves.

I guess. Though I got notification that my hard copy shipped, so I doubt they're going to revoke anything in it. Either way, I think it's more democratic to use the free rules, which anyone can access.

@nonymous Here in Germany, it will take another week or so before I can expect a hard copy to arrive. I can add the reference to the page # there once I get it (or earlier if someone lets me know which one it is)

@NobodytheHobgoblin, sounds good. Though, again, I think we should keep the free rules reference for common access

I already got my hard copy from my LGS, though I haven't flipped through it yet to find the actual page number. In the meantime, I have added a link to the DMG on D&D Beyond in addition to the Free Rules link.
